# Is archived lightning data from the GOES-16 beta test available?

Tags: lightning, weather-satellites

I was only able to find [real-time data](https://weather.msfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sportPublishData.pl?dataset=goes16glm&product=group). Or do I have to wait until the Geostationary Lightning Mapper is greenlit for production in 2018?

Comment: Did you try the [NOAA Class Archive](https://www.class.noaa.gov)?  They archive meteorological satellite data.  But perhaps not beta L2 products.